# Probit and Fama-Macbeth procedure

Tags: regression

I want to examine the predictive ability of volatility measures for returns prediction. One article used probit regression coefficient estimates to calculate Fama-Macbeth coefficient. I am so confused on this step. It would be great if someone explain to me the reason behind calculating Fama-Macbeth coefficient. Wouldn't be enough if I only run the probit regression without the Fama-Macbeth procedure?

Comment: Which article did you read?

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question completely, but im thinking the inital probit regression is just a way to measure sensitivities of assets to the volatility innovations. By then using these sensitivity estimates as explanatory variables in the fama-macbeth regressions, the premium from exposure to the more volatility sensitive assets can be estimated.